# Matlab: Divide a cell array of strings into 2 separate cell arrays

Tags: matlab

I have the following cell array:

`MyArray = {'12345'; '67890'; '12345'}`

I would like to create two new cell arrays that contain "split-up" versions of the above arrays.  In particular, I would like one cell array (`MyArray2`) to contain the first 3 characters of each element and the second cell array (`MyArray3`) to contain the last 2 characters of each element:

```
MyArray2 = {'123'; '678'; '123'}
MyArray3 = {'45'; '90'; '45'}
```

Is there some sort of "reverse" `strcat` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends how you want to split it. For your case (before your edit with square brackets) it's very easy:

```
A = ['12345'; '67890'; '12345']

B = A(:,1:3)
C = A(:,4:end)
```

For more complicated cases, have a look at `strsplit` (a quite new function, otherwise available at File Exchange)

---

Actually you mentioned you'd have a cell array, and also if your strings have different lengths it's a little more tricky. Have a look at the `cellfun` [documentation](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html).

```
days = {'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday'};

abbrev = cellfun(@(x) x(1:3), days, 'UniformOutput', false)
```

The syntax @(x) creates an anonymous function. This code returns

```
abbrev = 
    'Mon'    'Tue'    'Wed'    'Thu'    'Fri'
```

Therefore:

```
A = {'12345'; '67890'; '12345'}

B = cellfun(@(x) x(1:3), A, 'UniformOutput', false)
C = cellfun(@(x) x(4:5), A, 'UniformOutput', false)

B = 

    '123'
    '678'
    '123'


C = 

    '45'
    '90'
    '45'
```

Comment: I put in the square brackets instead of the curly brackets in my question above; I have fixed this.  Your second suggestion (using `cellfun`) works perfectly for what I need.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
sol = mat2cell(cell2mat(MyArray),ones(1,numel(MyArray)),[3 2]);
```

Your desired results are `sol(:,1)` and `sol(:,2)`:

```
>> sol(:,1)

ans = 

    '123'
    '678'
    '123'

>> sol(:,2)

ans = 

    '45'
    '90'
    '45'
```